# What is a sufficient condition for a complete graph to be representable on a von Neumann neighbourhood 2D grid?

Tags: graph-theory

Given a complete graph with integer weight values associated with each edge, I wish to represent this graph on a 2D square grid as follows:

- Each node is represented by a single square of the grid
- Each grid square can represent only one node
- The [Manhattan distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) between every pair of node-representing squares equals the weight of the edge between the represented nodes.

What properties must the graph have in order for this to be possible?

Comment: A lot of the time for small grids at least, at least some of the weights must be irrational, involving square roots.

Comment: @alan2here Actually I will measure the distance along the grid lines, not diagonally. Thus, all distances will be integers. I've edited this into the question now.

Comment: Perhaps a better title then, "What is ... a von Neumann neighbourhood 2D grid", also in the body a "square of the grid", as opposed to a "point somewhere on the grid".

Comment: lol, I make an edit suggestion and it's already better than my suggestion by the time I've finished it.